# Copying and Pasting Multiple Images and Text to/from Clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, clipboard

I'm working on a C# application where I need to implement functionality for copying and pasting multiple images along with associated text to and from the clipboard. Currently, I am using the Clipboard.SetDataObject method to store a single image and text, but I'm unsure how to extend this to support multiple items.

Here's a simplified version of my current code:

```
// Code for copying to clipboard
private void CopyToClipboard()
{
    Image image = GetImage(); // A method to get the image
    string text = GetText(); // A method to get the text

    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
    dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true, image);
    dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.Text, text);

    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, true);
}
```

How can I modify the code to support copying and pasting a list of images and associated text to and from the clipboard?
Is there a recommended format or serialization method for storing multiple images and text in the clipboard?
How should I adjust the CopyToClipboard and corresponding PasteFromClipboard methods to handle this scenario?
I appreciate any guidance or examples you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to assume you're on Windows here. Short answer: you can't. Long answer: The clipboard is only meant to hold one image at a time. There are some janky ways around it, like if you were to convert all the images to base64 and save it all as text, or even just combine the bytes of all the images and save that. These require you to also be in control of whatever you're pasting it into, though, and if that's the case, it would probably be better to just store the file paths rather than the actual images. Alternatively, you can enable clipboard history in Windows for an external solution.

Comment: Thanks for comment! I bet the best way is saving as text one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better idea is to store items in your application (in a database or something like a file) and show them to the user. when the user selects one of them you can set that item to the clipboard then. this is how clipboard managers work like [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/)